# How to load password protected pdf file in iframe without asking password dialog box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I have website in c# asp.net it having iframe control which loads/opens PDF file from client side using javascripts.

Here PDF file is password protected so when I am trying to load this PDF file in iframe it asking me password which I don't want it will open directly without asking password.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The answer may differ depending on whether only a user password, only an owner password, or both are used. It may also differ depending on the PDF viewer the PDF is opened in.

Answer (score 0):

If password protected PDF files are actually encrypted (and I think they are), this means that you really can't just open them without having the password. (At least, not without some very speedy hacking algorithm.)

EDIT: also see https://superuser.com/questions/56132/how-good-is-pdf-password-protection

Comment: ohhh..Means you are saying it's not possible. but i need to open a secured Password Protected pdf files programatically in asp.net using c# I don't want to enter the password manually when its opening time...but  when its in system it must ask the password to read or print the file.